# SQL Correlated Sub Query in Join statement time constraint

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a specific problem with Teradata SQL that I'm sure has an answer having to do with a correlated subquery...

Basically at the call center i work for, each agent must make a case (in a company CRM) for each call they take, and each case is linked to an account.  I need to get all the cases a group of agents created for a specific day, then get the very next case (if any) created on those accounts within the next 3 days.   Basically I need to take the following
(NOTE ALL CASES ARE DUMPED INTO THE SAME DB REGARDLESS OF CREATOR OR ACCOUNT NUMBER):

```
SELECT
  CASES.CASE_ID, CASES.CREATION_TIMESTAMP, CASES.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CASES.AGENT_ID
FROM
  CASES
WHERE CREATION_DATE = {d '2013-12-01'} AND AGENT_ID IN ('aaaaa','bbbbb','ccccc')
```

And somehow add 2 columns for the case ID and creation timestamp of the very next case created on each account like this:

```
SELECT
  INITIAL_CASES.CASE_ID, INITIAL_CASES.CREATION_TIMESTAMP,
  INITIAL_CASES.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  INITIAL_CASES.AGENT_ID,
  REPEAT.CASE_ID, REPEAT.CREATION_TIMESTAMP
FROM
  CASES AS INITIAL_CASES
LEFT JOIN

  (SELECT
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER, MIN(CREATION_TIMESTAMP) 
   FROM CASES 
   WHERE CREATION_TIMESTAMP > INITIAL_CASES.CREATION_TIMESTAMP 
   AND CREATION_DATE >= {d '2013-12-01'} 
   AND CREATION_DATE <= {d '2013-12-04'}) REPEAT

ON INITAL_CASES.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = REPEAT_CASES.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
WHERE AGENT_ID IN ('aaaaa','bbbbb','ccccc')
```

Some catches are that 1) There may be none or more than 1 case created on the same account after my agent created his case so i need to use a cobination of MIN(CREATION_TS) and a WHERE CREATION_TS > INITIAL_CREATION_TS   however this query needs to be preformed for each row in my initial result set of just my agents cases as they all have different timestamps.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: ...Why do you have columns `creation_date` _and_ `creation_timestamp`?  If they get out of sync, which one do you trust?  Or is there some use of which I'm unaware?  (Note that I don't consider extracting **dates** to be a useful optimization, as it's trivially derivable/queryable)  Also, why would you think different creators/accounts should have different dbs - is this some factor unique to Teradata?

Comment: Basically I work for a large company where neither I nor teams lateral to my own have any say in the creation or administration of the db, we are just reporting teams whom utilize it and whom are partitioned a db of our own to create and maintain our own tables in.  The data of course is stored/dumped into their tables.  Creation date is simply the rounded down timestamp and I was only using that as a filter in my example for simplification.    Also, to clarify, I was only stating that all cases are dumped in the same db to make sure it was clear that different centers dont have their own dbs

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need a self-join, seems you simply want the next rows data based on CREATION_TIMESTAMP (if it's within the next 3 days) and that's easy with Windowed Aggregates:

```
SELECT
  CASES.CASE_ID, CASES.CREATION_TIMESTAMP, CASES.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CASES.AGENT_ID,
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(CREATION_DATE)
         OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
               ORDER BY CREATION_TIMESTAMP
               ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) <= DATE '2013-12-04'
    THEN MIN(CASE_ID) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
               ORDER BY CREATION_TIMESTAMP
               ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS next_CASE_ID,
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(CREATION_DATE) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
               ORDER BY CREATION_TIMESTAMP
               ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) <= DATE '2013-12-04'
    THEN MIN(CREATION_TIMESTAMP) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
               ORDER BY CREATION_TIMESTAMP
               ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS next_CREATION_TIMESTAMP
FROM
  CASES
WHERE CREATION_DATE = {d '2013-12-01'} AND AGENT_ID IN ('aaaaa','bbbbb','ccccc')
```

Comment: Is the optimizer able to fold all the window functions into one, or is it going to be a separate invocation each time?

Comment: Yep, as long as both PARTITION and ORDER BY are the same the optimizer will do multiple functions in a single step.